# OpenCV w/ Rapsberry Pi: VideoCapture IP camera not working

Tags: java, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I'm working on a project that includes running opencv on the raspberry pi 3B in java. I've followed the instructions on its website for installation in linux, and uploaded my code:

```
cap = new VideoCapture();
cap.open("http://192.168.137.1:8000/video.mjpg");
System.out.println(cap.isOpened());
```

On my Windows computer, it prints out true, but on the Pi, it prints out false. However, I *am* able to wget the .mjpg file,  and it downloads fine. Also, it works with my usb camera (`cap.open(0);`).
I have found online that it could be ffmpeg, but I do have libav installed, so that should be fine. It worked on my Raspberry Pi model B, but not on my model 3 B.

Is there a set of libraries I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was able to figure out what was going on. Apparently, if you don't install the prerequisites FIRST, Cmake will take into account not having them, and will disable the feature completely. I was able to figure this out during the Cmake process, it stated it was "looking" for the libav libraries, and in turn did not find them. So, I decided to completely reinstall the OS, (probably didn't have to, but wanted to save space) and reinstall the prereq's first, then made sure the cmake compiler was happy before the make process. 
I guess that's why they call them pre-requisites, huh?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install the complete opencv package with all development dependencies?

```
apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

Comment: Yes I did, though I did so after building the opencv libraries from source. Would this affect it?